# Как получить значение ключа в api-ответе от сервера Json

Tags: php, json

Необходимо получить только номер телефона, чистый.

Казалось бы, что вопрос элементарный, но код, который я находил на просторах в интернете и который советовали мне тут не работает, хотя он выглядит правильно.

Как решали бы эту задачу все:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://smsc.ru/sys/get.php?get_messages=1&login=Alex&psw=123&cnt=1&fmt=3');

$responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
$responseObject = json_decode($response);

echo 'Телефон: ' . $responseArray[0]['phone'] . ' ';
```

И получаю: Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\MAMP\htdocs\sms.php on line 12

И только при таком условии, сервер возвращает json :

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://smsc.ru/sys/get.php?get_messages=1&login=Alex&psw=123&cnt=1&fmt=3');

echo $response;
```

Получаю:

```
[{ "status": 1, "last_date": "20.07.2023 21:52:33", "last_timestamp": 1689882753, "flag": 32, "send_date": "20.07.2023 21:52:32", "send_timestamp": 1689882752, "phone": "79999999999", "cost": "3.25" }]
```

var_dump пишет, что я получаю таким образом string, поэтому и не могу обратиться к ключу, как в массиве это делают

Не могу понять почему так

А если попробовать

```
    echo $response[0];
```

То выводит первую скобку "["

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($response));
а так?

Comment: NULL возвращает

Comment: Всё в порядке отрабатывает в [первом примере](https://onlinephp.io?s=fY9RSsNAEIbfC73DsAirUEI6S0waFfEEHiCEsiajsbTZJbt9EPHNk3iHPomeYb2Rs4XmoVT3afaf__tnBgDg-tZ2djrhCs4Gctb0juAGZPUKwnntt06UMJ-BWGvnl632xH-BaZLmCaaoAOdlhqVS4uDxzxticmMjeFksigLzTHH3ca2fWFPItaO-_ScNxcFzMi0m2M70ezpfjC9SjXE-yirBTMBbLa-OrrsbBv3CJ66c6ZctNaal87E5Az9s6YKZUbp_WFHj_wKidTqhpjMgw0fYhc-w-3kP3-GrBAnJ0dgqrSu531zW3JQQt_sF&v=8.2.8) ...

Comment: да, отрабатывает без вопросов, но именно когда подставляю api-запрос - стразу ошибки лезут, будто пустая переменная, хотя отдельно она выводится

Comment: `echo json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: попробовал api-запрос сделать, потом 
var_dump(json_decode($response));  и
echo json_last_error_msg()

Получил NULL Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: Не знаю поможет ли, но сталкивался с подобной ситуацией, когда сервер возвращал в json'е некоректный символ (символ был нечитаемый/непечатный и визуально его небыло видно, но он был и ломал json). Поэтому `json_decode` не мог его обработать. Нашёл его случайно перебирая стрелками посимволно строку с json'ом, и в одном месте нажимал стрелку, а курсор оставался на месте. Как вариант, можно попробовать ответ сервера предваритель обработать регуляркой, оставив только буквы, цифры... и посмотреть заработает ли код.